# How to change style of an input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give a

`-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px black;`

property to a text box as one focuses on it.

For example, here the background-color is being changed, but I want box-shadow instead.

```
<script>
function myFunction(x)
{
x.style.background="yellow";
}
</script>
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">
```

Comment: Try jQuery perhaps? Especially if you're doing a lot of this kind of thing

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking about an input or a div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use :focus in CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/VjLKV/

```
input {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px black;
}
```

Comment: Thankx. I didn't knew something like that exsisted.

Sincerely,
I am new to web designing and am 12 years old.

Comment: Wisdom: When I first started, I was under the general understanding that javascript could do anything, if it couldn't be done a different way, javascript was the solution.  While this in some ways can be very true, I learned to first explore every other possible way, especially when it comes to stylistic things.  If CSS can't do it, javascript/jquery probably can, but if you can do it in CSS, it's almost always a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Define css classes, and you can easily switch them as needed.

```
<script>
function myFunction(x)
{
x.style.className="yourcssclass";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JS for this, use the CSS pseudo-class `:focus`:

```
input[type="text"]:focus
{
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px black;
}
```

That way, the textbox will get the shadow when the user tabs into it, or clicks it, or whatever - and the styles will properly go away when they leave, and so on.

Remember to use the unprefixed version of the box-shadow style as well.

Comment: You have `:focus` confused for `:active`.